# Xamarin custom renderer System.ArgumentException when runs

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, renderer, custom-renderer

I've created a rendered picker's to center center in the middle of the control but at the moment of entering the page, it shows the following error: System.ArgumentException.

I attach the code to see if you can help me.

In project new class...

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MaterialFUR
{
    public class PickerCentrat : Picker
    {
    }
}
```

In Android ...

```
using MaterialFUR;
using MaterialFUR.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PickerCentrat), typeof(RendererPicker))]

namespace MaterialFUR.Droid
{
    public class RendererPicker : EntryRenderer
    {
        public RendererPicker(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML page...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MaterialFUR.AgafarMaterialPage"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MaterialFUR"
         Title="Agafar Material">
<ContentPage.Content>


    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="25">

        <Button x:Name="btnScan" Clicked="btnScan_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Gray" TextColor="White" Text="Llegir codi de barres"  FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" BorderRadius="30"/>
        <Entry x:Name="entCodi" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="Codi" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <Entry x:Name="entQtat" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Quantitat" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <local:PickerCentrat x:Name="pckUbicacio" Title="Ubicació" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold">
            <Picker.Items>
                <x:String>SATMOBIL-1</x:String>
                <x:String>SATMOBIL-2</x:String>
                <x:String>SATMOBIL-3</x:String>
                <x:String>SATMOBIL-4</x:String>
                <x:String>SATMOBIL-5</x:String>
                <x:String>SATMOBIL-6</x:String>
                <x:String>SATMOBIL-7</x:String>
                <x:String>SATMOBIL-8</x:String>
                <x:String>SATMOBIL-9</x:String>
                <x:String>TALLER</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
        </local:PickerCentrat>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,100">
            <Button x:Name="btnConfirmar" Clicked="BtnConfirmar_Clicked" BackgroundColor="SteelBlue" TextColor="White" Text="Confirmar" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" BorderRadius="30"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnCancelar" Clicked="BtnCancelar_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Gray" TextColor="White" Text="Cancelar" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" BorderRadius="30"/>
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>


</ContentPage.Content>
```

Error displayed.
[image]

I appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to Inherit from `PickerRenderer`

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PickerCentrat), typeof(RendererPicker))]

namespace MaterialFUR.Droid
{
    public class RendererPicker : PickerRenderer
    {
        public RendererPicker(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When in doubt about which class you need to Inherit from for your CustomRenderer, you can always check on the **Xamarin.Forms** source code [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers) (for Android).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also had to change the control in the OneElementChanged method.  Entry for Picker in my case. Thanks apineda.

Comment: Great! Yeah that also needed to be updated. Good you found it.

Comment: The docs also have a nice chart on what renderers to use as base renderers and what controls they map to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers